# Publishing delay based on permissions

Tags: 2010, security

We are about ready to grant access to outside partners and contractors to a site collection on our main SharePoint site. We would like just these partners and contractors to see everything in the site collection, but with a two day delay.

What is the best way to accomplish this on SharePoint 2010?

Comment: Can you expose your content to the outside users using publishing pages? Then, you could schedule the publishing start date of each of your pages to be be 2 days later.

Answer (score 2):

This may be a solution:

1. Create a site/library (source) with items for your own employees, partners/contracters would have no access to that place.
2. Create an empty site/library (target) with access for everyone.
3. Create a workflow that is attached to the items in the source library. Configure it so, that after two days, your items will be moved or copied to your partner site.

not to much of a job, no need to restore content databases. Problem with moving: history is lost. problem with copying: data is duplicated. You may have a small problem with a search, because both items would be indexed. BUt i think that this is a neat solution and I think it even fits into a sandboxed solution, could even be a sharepoint designer task ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sharepoint doesn't support something like this out of the box.

Create a New Web application and restore a 2 days older content database.

That's about the only thing I can think of. Sorry mate.